# Decrease skype icon in xubuntu tray

Tags: xubuntu, skype, xfce

Hello I am using Xubuntu 14.04. And skype in my tray looks like this:

[image]

In 13.10 icon looks well:

[image]

Is it possible to decrease size of it?

Thanks.

---

Is this problem fixed in 14.10? Could someone check?

Comment: It seems to be not possible (without a dissembler...) the icon for the notification area is hardcoded in the binary of skype. Read this funny discussion http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=988151

Comment: But why in 13.10 icon looks well?

http://www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-190514-141953.php

Comment: Thats a good question, i don't know...

Comment: @Xubu-Tur it's because xfce4-panel used scaling in that version but later developers turned it off because of speed lack. I made a bugreport about this.

Comment: could you provide link for your bugreport? Thanks for clarification.

Comment: OK. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-indicator-plugin/+bug/1313531. Note: I found your reply accidentally. To call me, use @ followed with my nick (@Danatela).

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed so it is possible now.
Right click on Notification area or right click on panel>>panel preferences>>items>>double click on Notification area and there you will find settings for icon size of applications in panel.

Comment: This problem is not actual since last releases.